# Clean way to add elements to fixed length array and removing the first element?

Tags: c

I need a clean way to add elements to an array, and if the array 'overflows', then the element at 0 must be replaced by element at 1, and so on, until a space frees up for the new element.

Here's an example (pseudocode):

```
array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// elements get added
array = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
...
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// Array is full!
// Another elements gets added
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
// And so on..
```

I tried doing this on an online compiler but I failed miserably and here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = { 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555, 555 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int arr_idx = i % 10;

        if (arr[10] != 555)
        {
            if (arr_idx < 9)
            {
                arr[arr_idx] = arr[arr_idx + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                arr[arr_idx] = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            arr[arr_idx] = i;
            printf("arr: %d", arr[arr_idx]);
        }

        printf("---\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d]Arr = %d\n", j, arr[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up ring buffers.  If you don't use a ring buffer, then you're hard pressed to avoid copying the data (use `memmove()` — do not use `memcpy()`) when you remove the element from the front.  Using a ring buffer, the starting position rotates around the array and adding an element involves overwriting a single array element and adjusting one counter.

Comment: Anyway, if you want a ring buffer - implement a ring buffer. These exercises with shifting are not very practical.

Comment: The ring buffer code looks pretty complicated. This is wayy harder than I thought. Might end up using a different method, I don't have much time to implement this.

Comment: Ring buffers themselves are pretty easy.  Adapting the code to use them might be a bit harder.  If your array size is small, then the memory copying isn't a big problem.  But what's OK for arrays of 16 integers isn't OK for arrays of millions of large structures.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd think that I need a size of 50-100 at most. I am working with a very slow ARM cpu, so I am not sure if memory copying can become a problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: there is no `arr[10]` in `arr[10]`!!

Comment: Note that `if (arr[10] != 555)` is accessing the array out of bounds.  That won't be helping your cause.

Comment: I don't actually see any code that shuffles the array down. It would be easier to see what's required, perhaps, if you had a function to add an entry to the array (parameter: new value to be added, and the array and the length in use), and another to remove the front item, and then a simple main program that called the add code twice for every one remove. You probably shouldn't be using sentinel values (555); you should have a count of how many items are already in use. Do you know about structures yet? If so, you can put the index and the array into a structure to be passed as a pointer.

Comment: Detail: "clean way to add elements to an array" -->  for clarity, an array cannot have elements "added" to it.  Once an array is defined, its size does not change.  Certainly code can assigned _some_ elements and not others, yet the array size is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither a ring buffer solution nor a 'shuffle buffer' solution is particularly complex.  Here's one of each.  Note that the ring buffer solution stores 15 values in an array of 16; the shuffle buffer solution use an array of size 15.  The solutions give the same sequence of outputs if you map the entries such as `( 1:  30)` to `(99: 30)` to allow for the differences in the way that the data is stored.

Both solutions assume you understand structures (and pointers to structures too).

#### Shuffle Buffer

This corresponds most closely to the code in the question.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { SB_SIZE = 15 };

typedef int Data;
#define DATA_PRI_FMT "d"

struct ShuffleBuffer
{
   size_t sb_last;
   Data   sb_data[SB_SIZE];
};
typedef struct ShuffleBuffer ShuffleBuffer;

static inline void sb_shuffle(ShuffleBuffer *sbp)
{
    if (sbp->sb_last > 0)
    {
        memmove(sbp->sb_data, sbp->sb_data + 1, (SB_SIZE - 1) * sizeof(sbp->sb_data[0]));
        sbp->sb_last--;
    }
}

static void sb_insert(ShuffleBuffer *sbp, Data value)
{
    if (sbp->sb_last == SB_SIZE)
        sb_shuffle(sbp);
    sbp->sb_data[sbp->sb_last++] = value;
}

static bool sb_remove(ShuffleBuffer *sbp, Data *valuep)
{
    if (sbp->sb_last == 0)
        return false;
    *valuep = sbp->sb_data[0];
    sb_shuffle(sbp);
    return true;
}

static void sb_print(const char *tag, const ShuffleBuffer *sbp)
{
    printf("%s: (last = %zu)\n", tag, sbp->sb_last);
    int nbytes = 0;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sbp->sb_last; i++)
    {
        nbytes += printf("%s(%2zu: %3" DATA_PRI_FMT ")", pad, i, sbp->sb_data[i]);
        if (nbytes > 40)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            nbytes = 0;
            pad = "";
        }
        else
            pad = " ";
    }
    if (nbytes != 0)
        putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    ShuffleBuffer rb = { 0, { 0 } };

    for (Data i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        sb_insert(&rb, i * 7 + 23);
        sb_print("Post insert", &rb);
        if ((i & 1) == 1)
        {
            Data value;
            if (sb_remove(&rb, &value))
                printf("Value %" DATA_PRI_FMT " removed\n", value);
            else
                sb_print("Ring Buffer Empty", &rb);
        sb_print("Post remove", &rb);
        }
    }

    printf("Insert/remove loop over\n");

    Data value;
    while (sb_remove(&rb, &value))
        printf("Value %" DATA_PRI_FMT " removed\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Ring Buffer

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { RB_SIZE = 16 };

typedef int Data;
#define DATA_PRI_FMT "d"

struct RingBuffer
{
   size_t rb_head;
   size_t rb_tail;
   Data   rb_data[RB_SIZE];
};
typedef struct RingBuffer RingBuffer;

static inline size_t rb_nextpos(size_t pos)
{
    return (pos + 1) % RB_SIZE;
}

static void rb_insert(RingBuffer *rbp, Data value)
{
    rbp->rb_data[rbp->rb_head] = value;
    rbp->rb_head = rb_nextpos(rbp->rb_head);
    if (rbp->rb_tail == rbp->rb_head)
        rbp->rb_tail = rb_nextpos(rbp->rb_tail);
}

static bool rb_remove(RingBuffer *rbp, Data *valuep)
{
    if (rbp->rb_head == rbp->rb_tail)
        return false;
    *valuep = rbp->rb_data[rbp->rb_tail];
    rbp->rb_tail = rb_nextpos(rbp->rb_tail);
    return true;
}

static void rb_print(const char *tag, const RingBuffer *rbp)
{
    printf("%s: (head = %zu, tail = %zu)\n", tag, rbp->rb_head, rbp->rb_tail);
    int nbytes = 0;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (size_t i = rbp->rb_tail; i != rbp->rb_head; i = rb_nextpos(i))
    {
        nbytes += printf("%s(%2zu: %3" DATA_PRI_FMT ")", pad, i, rbp->rb_data[i]);
        if (nbytes > 40)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            nbytes = 0;
            pad = "";
        }
        else
            pad = " ";
    }
    if (nbytes != 0)
        putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    RingBuffer rb = { 0, 0, { 0 } };

    for (Data i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        rb_insert(&rb, i * 7 + 23);
        rb_print("Post insert", &rb);
        if ((i & 1) == 1)
        {
            Data value;
            if (rb_remove(&rb, &value))
                printf("Value %" DATA_PRI_FMT " removed\n", value);
            else
                rb_print("Ring Buffer Empty", &rb);
        rb_print("Post remove", &rb);
        }
    }

    printf("Insert/remove loop over\n");

    Data value;
    while (rb_remove(&rb, &value))
        printf("Value %" DATA_PRI_FMT " removed\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler is so antiquated that it doesn't recognize `inline` as a keyword, simply add `#define inline /* C99 not available */` near the top of the file (or, better, get a compiler that does recognize the almost 20-year old standard).

#### Sample output from Ring Buffer

```
Post insert: (head = 1, tail = 0)
( 0:  23)
Post insert: (head = 2, tail = 0)
( 0:  23) ( 1:  30)
Value 23 removed
Post remove: (head = 2, tail = 1)
( 1:  30)
Post insert: (head = 3, tail = 1)
( 1:  30) ( 2:  37)
Post insert: (head = 4, tail = 1)
( 1:  30) ( 2:  37) ( 3:  44)
Value 30 removed
Post remove: (head = 4, tail = 2)
( 2:  37) ( 3:  44)
Post insert: (head = 5, tail = 2)
( 2:  37) ( 3:  44) ( 4:  51)
Post insert: (head = 6, tail = 2)
( 2:  37) ( 3:  44) ( 4:  51) ( 5:  58)
Value 37 removed
Post remove: (head = 6, tail = 3)
( 3:  44) ( 4:  51) ( 5:  58)
Post insert: (head = 7, tail = 3)
( 3:  44) ( 4:  51) ( 5:  58) ( 6:  65)
Post insert: (head = 8, tail = 3)
( 3:  44) ( 4:  51) ( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72)
Value 44 removed
Post remove: (head = 8, tail = 4)
( 4:  51) ( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72)
Post insert: (head = 9, tail = 4)
( 4:  51) ( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79)
Post insert: (head = 10, tail = 4)
( 4:  51) ( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79)
( 9:  86)
Value 51 removed
Post remove: (head = 10, tail = 5)
( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86)
Post insert: (head = 11, tail = 5)
( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86)
(10:  93)
Post insert: (head = 12, tail = 5)
( 5:  58) ( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86)
(10:  93) (11: 100)
Value 58 removed
Post remove: (head = 12, tail = 6)
( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93)
(11: 100)
Post insert: (head = 13, tail = 6)
( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93)
(11: 100) (12: 107)
Post insert: (head = 14, tail = 6)
( 6:  65) ( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93)
(11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114)
Value 65 removed
Post remove: (head = 14, tail = 7)
( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100)
(12: 107) (13: 114)
Post insert: (head = 15, tail = 7)
( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100)
(12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121)
Post insert: (head = 0, tail = 7)
( 7:  72) ( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100)
(12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128)
Value 72 removed
Post remove: (head = 0, tail = 8)
( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128)
Post insert: (head = 1, tail = 8)
( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135)
Post insert: (head = 2, tail = 8)
( 8:  79) ( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142)
Value 79 removed
Post remove: (head = 2, tail = 9)
( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114)
(14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142)
Post insert: (head = 3, tail = 9)
( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114)
(14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149)
Post insert: (head = 4, tail = 9)
( 9:  86) (10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114)
(14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149)
( 3: 156)
Value 86 removed
Post remove: (head = 4, tail = 10)
(10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121)
(15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156)
Post insert: (head = 5, tail = 10)
(10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121)
(15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156)
( 4: 163)
Post insert: (head = 6, tail = 10)
(10:  93) (11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121)
(15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156)
( 4: 163) ( 5: 170)
Value 93 removed
Post remove: (head = 6, tail = 11)
(11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128)
( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163)
( 5: 170)
Post insert: (head = 7, tail = 11)
(11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128)
( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163)
( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
Post insert: (head = 8, tail = 11)
(11: 100) (12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128)
( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163)
( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184)
Value 100 removed
Post remove: (head = 8, tail = 12)
(12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135)
( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170)
( 6: 177) ( 7: 184)
Post insert: (head = 9, tail = 12)
(12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135)
( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170)
( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191)
Post insert: (head = 10, tail = 12)
(12: 107) (13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135)
( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170)
( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198)
Value 107 removed
Post remove: (head = 10, tail = 13)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142)
( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198)
Post insert: (head = 11, tail = 13)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142)
( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205)
Post insert: (head = 12, tail = 13)
(13: 114) (14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142)
( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212)
Value 114 removed
Post remove: (head = 12, tail = 14)
(14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149)
( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184)
( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212)
Post insert: (head = 13, tail = 14)
(14: 121) (15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149)
( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184)
( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212) (12: 219)
Post insert: (head = 14, tail = 15)
(15: 128) ( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156)
( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191)
( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212) (12: 219) (13: 226)
Value 128 removed
Post remove: (head = 14, tail = 0)
( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163)
( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198)
(10: 205) (11: 212) (12: 219) (13: 226)
Post insert: (head = 15, tail = 0)
( 0: 135) ( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163)
( 5: 170) ( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198)
(10: 205) (11: 212) (12: 219) (13: 226) (14: 233)
Post insert: (head = 0, tail = 1)
( 1: 142) ( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170)
( 6: 177) ( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205)
(11: 212) (12: 219) (13: 226) (14: 233) (15: 240)
Value 142 removed
Post remove: (head = 0, tail = 2)
( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212)
(12: 219) (13: 226) (14: 233) (15: 240)
Post insert: (head = 1, tail = 2)
( 2: 149) ( 3: 156) ( 4: 163) ( 5: 170) ( 6: 177)
( 7: 184) ( 8: 191) ( 9: 198) (10: 205) (11: 212)
(12: 219) (13: 226) (14: 233) (15: 240) ( 0: 247)
…
Post insert: (head = 3, tail = 4)
( 4: 611) ( 5: 618) ( 6: 625) ( 7: 632) ( 8: 639)
( 9: 646) (10: 653) (11: 660) (12: 667) (13: 674)
(14: 681) (15: 688) ( 0: 695) ( 1: 702) ( 2: 709)
Post insert: (head = 4, tail = 5)
( 5: 618) ( 6: 625) ( 7: 632) ( 8: 639) ( 9: 646)
(10: 653) (11: 660) (12: 667) (13: 674) (14: 681)
(15: 688) ( 0: 695) ( 1: 702) ( 2: 709) ( 3: 716)
Value 618 removed
Post remove: (head = 4, tail = 6)
( 6: 625) ( 7: 632) ( 8: 639) ( 9: 646) (10: 653)
(11: 660) (12: 667) (13: 674) (14: 681) (15: 688)
( 0: 695) ( 1: 702) ( 2: 709) ( 3: 716)
Insert/remove loop over
Value 625 removed
Value 632 removed
Value 639 removed
Value 646 removed
Value 653 removed
Value 660 removed
Value 667 removed
Value 674 removed
Value 681 removed
Value 688 removed
Value 695 removed
Value 702 removed
Value 709 removed
Value 716 removed
```

#### Timing

With the main loop repeating 100 times, there's not really a measurable difference between the two programs if you disable the printing, and its only barely measurable and not entirely reliable if you enable the printing.

With printing disabled and the buffer size of 15 or 16, looping one million times in the main program took 4.5 ms for ring buffer vs 9.0 ms for shuffle buffer.  Change the buffer size to 2047 or 2048, and the times were 3.7 ms for ring buffer vs 87.3 ms for shuffle buffer.  With the printing enabled, the slight extra work done by ring buffer in the printing swamped the performance gain from not shuffling; the two programs were running in essentially the same time: 4,546.5 ms vs 4,477.2 ms (so shuffle buffer was slightly faster with the printing enabled — in large part because it produced only 353 MiB of data compared with 368 MiB of data from the ring buffer — with the data being written to `/dev/null` with the timing runs).

The measured times were elapsed run time for the executable — not CPU time per se.  The testing was done an a 15" MacBook Pro (2017) with 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 with 16 GiB of 2133 MHz [LPDDR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPDDR) RAM, running macOS 10.14.3 Mojave and using a home-built GCC 8.2.0.  Speed testing is difficult — I think the results without printing are meaningful, but [YMMV](https://www.acronymfinder.com/YMMV.html).  If you ever needed a demonstration that 'printing is slow', this is quite possibly a good one.